# Are consulting solicitations acceptable?

Tags: discussion, editing-help, self-promotion

A user was offering consulting services as part of an answer.  Is this acceptable according to Stack Overflow policy?

Recently [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28018914/revisions) ended up in the VLQ queue. Upon looking at it, I felt (with some minor discussion with peers) that when he offered his services (and a link to payment) that it was clutter, and thus [my review was editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13147421).

Was this edit correct? Should I have handled this differently?

Comment: Thanks for asking this - I was the flagger of this answer. It offered no useful information beyond common sense and only existed to promote himself and get Google juice to his 'pay-me' page. The "I've done this in a poor way, but you will have to pay me to get my code" was insulting, especially from such a high-rep user. And, at the time of his response to my first comment, an upvote magically appeared on his answer which I'd report for shill voting if I could. All-in I thought a poor answer from someone who should know better - I was totally surprised my first spam flag got denied over it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Soliciting work in answers is a no-no.

- It's against our self-promotion policy
- More importantly, it's against our fundamental expectations of what is a good answer.

  - job solicitation info is bound to become stale, relevant mostly to the OP at this point in time. It is unlikely to be useful information for future generations. We *hate* that.
  - Answers are expected to contain information that stands on its own. We even frown upon relying on external links; how can we not frown upon this, where the information is hidden not behind a link, but behind hiring someone to do the work?
  - If the person soliciting the job is the *only* way to get the information the OP is asking for (like, because they own the software), then the question is by definition off topic for Stack Overflow, as we deal in *answerable* questions - so that's not an excuse, either.

In a scenario like this, if you have the *perfect* service for an OP who clearly needs it, leave a comment. But definitely don't embed your offer in your answer.

If you see something like this, I would either edit the self-promotion out, or flag for moderator attention. If the answer is otherwise worthwhile, a spam flag is not warranted.

Comment: Also, given that this answer was from a 20k user with a history of good behavior, I'd give them the benefit of the doubt. An edit to remove the promotional material and a polite comment about this might be sufficient. I think it's pretty safe to say that they're not a spammer.

Comment: @BradLarson just because someone isn't a spammer it doesn't mean they'll never post spam. Also, a 20k user _should_ know what not to post.

Comment: If anyone needs help determining if an answer fits this model my services are available. (for a small fee)

Comment: This was exactly my thoughts exactly, but my first spam flag was denied!

Comment: @user because a spam flag is way over the top here.

Comment: see, i disagree because the majority of it was elaborating"i've done it... i'm not going to post the code here, but you can pay me money then you can have it". the 'morsel' of information was just a link to the docs which a 2s google search would turn up.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think the problem lies in the question: it is a bit broad to begin with. It basically asks 'How can I do X with Y', so it can attract all kind of answers we normally don't want. The accepted answer is a link to a Github project with some information about how to install and use it. If the project ever moves, it's unusable. In my opinion, offering a licensed library/paid service is not really a worse answer, and I would not have removed the link.

If the author makes a lot of other posts promoting his service/library, even if it is not applicable, *that* would qualify for a ♦ moderator investigation. In such cases, *it doesn't matter if the service is free or not*.

Posting about your service seems to be allowed under certain conditions, as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.