# Consulting on over-specific questions

Tags: discussion

Many questions are over-specific to the asker. A very common source of these questions is around porting custom encryption schemes between languages. They're over-specific because so many crypto implementations are ad hoc, so no one else is likely to have the same situation. And most developers know almost nothing about cryptography, so they aren't able to adapt examples to even slightly different problems.

For example, just in the last week (none have any answers at this time):

- [Decryption algorithm for encrypted data in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869260/decryption-algorithm-for-encrypted-data-in-js)
- [String Encrypted in Java need to Decrypt in Angular 6 using AES-256-GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868489/string-encrypted-in-java-need-to-decrypt-in-angular-6-using-aes-256-gcm)
- [Python code snippet to java code equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855473/python-code-snippet-to-java-code-equivalent)
- [AES 256 Encryption Decryption,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826271/aes-256-encryption-decryption)
- [AES-256-CTR encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822641/aes-256-ctr-encryption)
- [Decryption fails for AES CBC 128 bit using OpenSSL using the EVP API in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786299/decryption-fails-for-aes-cbc-128-bit-using-openssl-using-the-evp-api-in-c)
- [Decrypt and encrypt Text using certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57782060/decrypt-and-encrypt-text-using-certain-key)

These kinds of questions often get downvoted or closed, but often they're just ignored. I used to answer them, but they're very time consuming. And because the schemes are often highly insecure (but difficult to change for compatibility reasons), I don't want future searchers to copy my code.

I do exactly this kind of work (custom crypto implementations) on a consulting basis. I'm happy to volunteer with SO when the answers will be broadly valuable, but I'm not willing to port ad hoc, broken crypto schemes as a volunteer.

I would like a way to say "if you have trouble getting an answer, please contact me about consulting." I've actually posted comments along this line in some cases, but I'm not sure it's good practice. Another contributor objected, and I think they were right to say something. I'm not sure how I feel about it myself.

Previously, [Are consulting solicitations acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329915/are-consulting-solicitations-acceptable) suggested that a comment like this may be acceptable, but it wasn't suggesting it as a practice (and was mostly saying "not in answers").

I hate to see developers struggling when I could fix their problems quickly, and it's literally my job to do so, but I'm not sure what to do about it in this case. Just closing the questions seems the by-the-book Stack Overflow approach, but I want to be able to do more for the OP.

Comment: At best you can use your about me to share your consulting options. Nagging users and visitors in comments is an practice to stay away from. Maybe use chat but even that is tricky.

Comment: SO in general is highly allergic to commercial messaging or using the platform for advertising in any way. Maybe you could buy an ad from SO, Inc to show up in relevant tags only? I do wish there were a way to tag or close a question as “unwarranted expectation that someone will provide an answer to this for free”. We get a LOT of “please provide me free consulting questions that entire industries exist to trade in” questions. In all sorts of stacks, tags, industries and professions. I’ve seen it on EL&U, ELL, Electronics, and yesterday even in Chemistry.